# VBA Compile Error Expected Sub, Function Or Property

Tags: excel, vba, function, properties

I keep getting the compile error resposne Expected Sub, Function or Property, when trying to run below VBA code. The problem is with the called sub procedure. Any insight as to why will be appreciated.

```
        Result5iii = Result6i - Result4
        ResultGi = Result5iii - Range("G2").Value
                        Range("W3").Value = ("ResultGi")
                        Range("X3").Value = (" Can Use: [ " & ResultGi & " ]")
                        Range("Y3").Value = ("2 Nxt will not be " & ResultGi)
                        Range("Z3").Value = (" 19|15|5ii ")
                        
                        'Minus1Rule_OriginalsG'
                            If Result5iii = 5 And Range("G2").Value = 1 And ResultGi = 4. Then
                                Call Minus1Rule_5OriginalsG
```

The called Procedure is;

```
Public Sub Minus1Rule_5OriginalsG()
Dim ResultG As Double, Result5i As Double, Result1 As Double, Result1a As Double

'1. -1 Rule'

'For Originals'
        Range("W2").Value = (" 0, 5 [ " & ResultG & " ]")
        Range("X2").Value = (" Can Use:  0, 5 [ " & ResultG & " ]")
        Range("Y2").Value = ("2 Nxt will not be " & "0, 5" & "Reason: -1 Rule For Originals")
        Range("Z2").Value = (Result1 & "|" & Result1a & " 5 - 1" & "|" & "5i ")

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is `Minus1Rule_5OriginalsG()`in relations to the Sub calling it? A different module, or something else?

Comment: You are missing an `End If` at the end of your first block of code

Comment: @Christofer Weber Minus1Rule_5OriginalsG() is in the same module. Although I also have it in other (test) Modules, but I dont think that should matter right?

Comment: @JohnM - End If is included at the end of code block. I just didnt write out the full code here

Comment: It should use the one in the same module, otherwise throw a naming error, not a [expected-sub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/expected-sub-function-or-property) error. 
But unless it's misspelled, not sure why it would do that then.